# Whenever I create an active tab link or a button in a navigation bar, it adds a minus sign after the text

Tags: html, css, tabs, navigation

Example code for the button:

```
<button class='active' id=\"defaultOpen\">Patient Falls Info</button>
```

CSS for id and class is now added. I've tried commenting out the code, but it hasn't helped me in any way unfortunately

```
.navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
top: 0;
}

.navbar button {
background-color: inherit;
float: left;
color: white;
border: none;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 14px 16px;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar button:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

.navbar button.active {
background-color: #666;
color: white;
}
```

Navigation bar example:

[image]

Comment: share your code

Comment: Hey Vikas. Unfortunately, I can't copy and paste all my code (for university plagiarism reasons). Is there a particular section of code you would want to see?

Comment: @TegSingh Show as much as needed to demonstrate the problem. Your one line of code does not.

Comment: share the css for the class and the id

Comment: I have now added the css code for the class, There was no css code or ID. Thank you everyone for your messages!

Comment: Try inspecting the element with *Developers Tools* builtin to your browser. Right click on the nav. menu link and selecting *Inspect* or *Inspect element* should open the Developer tools for you. Can you see there the dash inside the `<button>` tags?

Comment: Hi Kizivat! 

There is no dash after i inspect the element. However ::after gets added at the ended when the tab is active. This (::after) is what is adding the minus sign. I'm not too sure why..

Comment: I've managed to fix the problem by making my


    `.button navbar.active::after {
        display: none;
    }`

thank you everyone for your help!